# querying opening Hours, late night In Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Openinghours Table and I want to query through so that I get the closing time of a Location.

Here is an instance of the OpeningHoursTable and my code current query Code, that dosn't work, however you might get an Idea...

For instance  day_id = 3,

is open from 11:30 till 14:30. and from 17:30 till 00:00 next Day.

I Woud like to have 0000 of day 4 outputted

How can I query this?

Database entries:

```
location_id | day_id | opened | closed

    81          1        1130    1430       
    81          1        1730        
    81          2                0000   
    81          3        1130    1430   
    81          3        1730       
    81          4                0000   
    81          4        1130    1430   
    81          4        1730       
    81          5                0000   
    81          5        1130    1430   
    81          5        1730       
    81          6                0000   
    81          6        1130    1430   
    81          6        1730       
    81          7                0000   
    81          7        1130    1430   
    81          7        1730       
    81          1                0000
```

My "idea" of Code in Location.php :

```
public function closesTodayAt($closeTo = 2000)
    {   
        $thisDay = today()->dayOfWeek + 1;

        $time = $this->openinghours()->where('day_id', $thisDay)->where('closed','!=', "")
                        orWhere()->get();

        if ($time->first()->closed < $closeTo ) {
            #code
        }
        if ($time < $closeTo ) {
            $nextDay = today()->addDay(1)->dayOfWeek +1;
            $time = $this->openinghours()->where('day_id', $thisDay)->where('opened','!=',"")->first()->opened;
        }
        if ($time === "0000") {
            # code...
        }
        $time = str_split($time,2);
        $time = implode(":", $time);
        return $time;
    }
```

Here another part of the Database:

```
94  1   1100    
94  2       0100
94  2   1100    
94  3       0100
94  3   1100    
94  4       0100
94  4   1100    
94  5       0100
94  5   1100    
94  6       0200
94  6   1100    
94  7       0400
94  7   1100    
94  1       0400
```

Comment: Check https://github.com/spatie/opening-hours

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, the closing hours would always be the earliest found hours of the next day, so simply taking the hours for the next day, sorting and taking the first record would get you the closing time:

```
public function scopeCloses($query)
{
    $nextDayOfWeek = now()->addDay()->dayOfWeek;

    $hours= $this->openinghours->where('day_id', $nextDayOfWeek)
                               ->sortBy('closes')
                               ->first();
    return $hours->closes;
}
```

Comment: On the assumption every location closes at midnight or later this will work fine, OP should be careful to account for a closing time earlier than midnight the next day unless sure the scope will never change.